# Jquery event only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

please help a jquery/javascript noob, I guess this is a common issue and I have tried things like changing my .on method to .delegate and .live .. but this has not helped. My problem is that the background image changes on the first click only.

HTML

```
      <article class="panel" id="imgLoader">
        <figure class="imgBG img1">
        </figure>
      </article><!-- end panel -->
      <div class="panel" id="imgSlides">
        <ul class="column">
          <li id="img1" class="imgBG img1"></li>
          <li id="img2" class="imgBG img2"></li>
          <li id="img3" class="imgBG img3"></li>
          <li id="img4" class="imgBG img4"></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- end panel -->
```

CSS

```
/*---------------------
     Img Classes
---------------------*/
.imgBG {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img1 {
  background-image: url('../images/signupbg1.jpg');
}
.img2 {
  background-image: url('../images/signupbg2.jpg');
}
.img3 {
  background-image: url('../images/signupbg3.jpg');
}
.img4 {
  background-image: url('../images/signupbg4.jpg');
}
```

Jquery

```
$(function() {

  $('#img2').on('click', function() {

    $('#imgLoader figure').removeClass('img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img4').addClass('img2');

  });

  $('#img3').on('click', function() {

    $('#imgLoader figure').removeClass('img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img4').addClass('img3');

  });

});
```

I have also tried just using .css('background-image', 'url()'); as well.. but for some reason was receiving errors.. Thanks.

Comment: Try removeClass("class1 class2") as the params are space delimited and NOT comma!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `removeClass` method doesn't take multiple parameters, it takes a space separated string of class names:

```
$('#imgLoader figure').removeClass('img1 img2 img3 img4').addClass('img2');
```